# Вопрос по Windows аутентификации с NTLM в Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, ntlm

Добрый день. Вопрос по Windows аутентификации с NTLM в Asp.Net Core. Нужно реализовать такую штуку.Подскажите или направьте кто сталкивался.Очень нужно.Благодарю

Comment: Мои попытки http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891843/c-как-сделать-ntlm-сквозную-авторизацию-на-сервере

Answer (score 0):

Если хоститесь на IIS тогда он может решить за вас эту проблему. Если нет, то готовых решений пока нет.

Comment: Да.Хочу на IIS, а какое готовое решение, не подскажете ? или ссылкой не поделитесь ?Спасибо

Comment: Ставите тип авторизации Windows и всё.